# Is there a way to query what other apps are on a device

Tags: ios

Does iOS offer a way for an app to query the device for information about what other apps are installed/running?

Comment: Can't be done without jailbreaking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All ios apps are sandboxed so this wouldn't be possible on a non-jailbroken device

Comment: right, I was sort of hoping that there was some native OS bridge or API that acted as a safe information retriever about some aspects of what else was on the device. I guess there's no such thing?

Comment: btw; There are a few ways to share data between your own apps, but this won't help you detect any other apps.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options.

First, you can lookup for the specific process name of the app, but this may be prone to error as unrelated apps may be running using the same process name, for example, I've seen both the Batman and Dark Meadow game share a similar process name: UDKGame.

Secondly, using the URL scheme. This method is useful if you know what apps you are looking for and you know that this particular app implements the URL scheme. You can do a simple canOpenURL and find out if that app is installed.

I use the second method a lot to collect the URL schemes for use in my app, AppSwitch.